# Linq Query Suggestion

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have query as below. A product can be assigned to multiple products so after this linq query I am getting multiple products in result. How do I change it so that I can see one product only once .

```
var list = (from p in Products from cat in p.Product_SubCategory_Mappings
       let trend = CustomFunction(p.ID) where cat.SubCategory.CategoryId == 19 && 
       trend > 100 select new { Product = p, p.Vendor, trend}).ToList();
```

Here is table structure if it helps

1. Products  -->                   ProductID | Name | Price | VendorID
2. Category  -->                   CategoryID | Label
3. SubCategory-->                  SubCategoryID | Label | ParentID
4. Product_SubCategory_Mapping-->  ProductID | SubCategoryID

Comment: By "multiple business" do you mean "multiple vendors"?  Also, can you give some actual sample output, and desired sample output?  It is hard to tell what you are looking for (e.g. do you want to query based on vendor Id, so that only a single vendor is output? or just group by vendor Id?)

Comment: Sorry its products not business.

Comment: It is a little easier to tell what you are asking now that you said "one product".  When I thought you meant one vendor it was confusing, and one business didn't make any sense at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do a sub-select on `Product.Product_SubCategory_Mappings`, you are multiplying the number of rows in your result set by the number of sub-category mappings you have for each product.  This means products will be duplicated.

To avoid this, you can [use the `Any` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) instead of a sub-select.

Something like this:

```
var list = (from p in Products
            let trend = CustomFunction(p.ID)
            let cats = p.Product_SubCategory_Mappings
            where trend > 100
                && cats.Any(cat => cat.SubCategory.CategoryId == 19)
            select new { Product = p, p.Vendor, trend }
            )
            .ToList();
```

Comment: This is not working . It shows error cats does not contain definition for Any .

Comment: @Sonesh: You must include a `using` statement for the extension method in order for it to compile.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx (`using System.Linq`)

Comment: I already have using statement and that's reason previous query is working fine on the page.

Comment: @Sonesh: What type is `Product_SubCategory_Mappings`?  If it is an `IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>` it should work.  Also, have you included a reference to `System.Core.dll`?  Check the MSDN docs I linked in my previous comment (and now in the answer itself).  That methods exists - something is wrong with the way it is being used.

Comment: Product_SubCategory_Mappings is a table in SQL server which I am querying on.

Comment: @Sonesh: What is the type of the variable?  `DataRow`?  `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: Well its querying database.I think it should be IQueryable. I ended up doing this .var list = (from p in Products
            let trend = CustomFunction(p.ID)
            where p.Product_SubCategory_Mappings.Any(sub => .SubCategory.CategoryId == 19) AND
             trend > 100
            select new { Product = p, p.Vendor, trend }
            )
            .ToList();

Comment: You help with .Any quite gave me direction so I would mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

this may be work

```
 public IQueryable<Product> GetProduct()
        {

            var list = (from p in Products
                        from cat in p.Product_SubCategory_Mappings
                        let trend = CustomFunction(p.ID)
                        where cat.SubCategory.CategoryId == 19 &&
                              trend > 100
                        select new {Product = p, p.Vendor, trend}).Distinct();
            return list;
        }
```